# Finding the current Accelerometer values

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, gravity, devicemotion

I'm trying to get a label to rotate based on the tit of the device in an app I'm making in swift. Given that I should be fine with rotating the label, does anybody know how to find the current accelerometer values of an iPhone? For example, getting it to print its x, y and z values once every second or so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

1. Add the framework
2. Add the following code in the appropriate places

   ```
   import CoreMotion

   var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
   var AccelX: CGFloat = 0

   // Setup accelemeter detection

   if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == true {
       motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue(), withHandler: { (data, error) -> Void in
           self.outputAccelertionData(data.acceleration)
       })
   }

   func outputAccelertionData (acceleration: CMAcceleration) {
       AccelX = 0

       if fabs(CGFloat(acceleration.x)) > fabs(AccelX) {
           AccelX = CGFloat(acceleration.x)
       }
   }
   ```